# Calling Java method from JRuby throws "no constructor for arguments error"

Tags: java, jruby, constraints, knapsack-problem, jacop

I'm trying to initialize [this class](http://jacopapi.osolpro.com/JaCoP/constraints/knapsack/Knapsack.html#Knapsack%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20JaCoP.core.IntVar%5B%5D,%20JaCoP.core.IntVar,%20JaCoP.core.IntVar%29) from the JaCop constraint programming library from jRuby. I am using the correct type of arguments, but for some reason I keep getting this error message:

```
  NameError: no constructor for arguments
    (
      org.jruby.RubyArray,
      org.jruby.RubyArray,
      org.jruby.RubyArray,
      JaCoP.core.IntVar,
      JaCoP.core.IntVar)
    on Java::JaCoPConstraintsKnapsack::Knapsack
    (root) at rb/knapsack.rb:24
```

The code that it points to is this:

```
k = Jacop::Knapsack.new(@values, @weights, quantity, knapsackCapacity, knapsackProfit)
```

The signature of the Java class constructor is this:

```
public Knapsack(int[] profits,
                int[] weights,
                IntVar[] quantity,
                IntVar knapsackCapacity,
                IntVar knapsackProfit)
```

I don't understand why jRuby complains that constructor is not found because it should be able to find this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JRuby can not always guess "complicated" method args for you, you might want to try :

`Jacop::Knapsack.new(@values, @weights, quantity.to_java(JaCoP.core.IntVar), knapsackCapacity, knapsackProfit)`

or even helping with the `int[]` cast (should not be necessary) :

`Jacop::Knapsack.new(@values.to_java(:int), @weights.to_java(:int), quantity.to_java(JaCoP.core.IntVar), knapsackCapacity, knapsackProfit)`

Comment: You were absolutely right. I had to cast the ints as well to make it work.